# ActionScript to Haxe

Tags: flash, actionscript, converters, haxe

Is it possible to convert ActionScript 3 to Haxe? I have seen a converter on the Haxe website but I have no idea on how to use it! All it is, is a bunch of code which I am not understanding. If someone would show me how to use it, it would be a great help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently converted quite a large project from Actionscript 3 to Haxe and I'd strongly suggest doing it manually yourself: the conversion tools I used did not seem entirely reliable (and required a *lot* of manual fixes anyway) and, in the process, you will begin to learn the key differences between the two languages.

This [AS3 to Haxe cheat sheet](https://books.openfl.org/as3-conversion-guide/glossary/cheat-sheet.html) should allow you to do a simple Find and Replace on the most basic changes (e.g. `void` => `Void`, `public class MyClass` => `class MyClass`) and clearly outlines the differences on slightly more complicated ones that Find and Replace may not be able to handle alone (e.g. loops, casting, reflection).

This [comparison of an AS3 to Haxe code snippet](https://books.openfl.org/as3-conversion-guide/) should also help your understanding if the cheat sheet is not clear enough.

Comment: Thank you, one more thing. Are those ALL of the differences? E.g Am I able to look through my AS3 code and change it according to the differences? And do you think I am able to contact you (email etc) if I have any more questions? Thanks

Comment: As far as I am aware, that cheat sheet should cover just about everything you need to know. With this and a bit of Googling, I was able to convert a reasonably sized AS3 game to Haxe with no prior experience and get it running on an iPhone in under a day. After experiencing the performance improvements and the ease of compiling to Flash/EXE/mobile I can honestly say I'm never returning to Actionscript.

If you do get stuck, I'd suggest either continuing to post specific questions on here or popping into the Haxe (http://haxe.org/forum) or OpenFL (http://www.openfl.org/developer/forums/) forums

Comment: Ok thanks your a great help, another question, currently I'm new to Actionscript 3. I've been doing a book about it. I Am about 100 pages through it. Should I learn haXe by learning Actionscript 3 and adapting the differences or just learn haXe. The reason why I dont to learn haXe is because theres not enough support for it. So what should I do?

Comment: I tried porting a large project automatically (as3tohx I think..) and it was a disaster. Even the import statements were messed up. I'm porting it manually now

Answer (score 2):

I have ported as3tohx convertor(from Caffeine-hx repository) to Haxe 3.

It's not perfect, and can throw bugs, but you can save some time if you use it.

```
as3tohx folder/with/as3/code
```

as3tohx will generate *output* folder with Haxe code.

https://github.com/as3boyan/as3tohxfromcaffeine-hx